# Get content under co-ordinates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement an element that zooms the part of the image on hover of it - something like you see on e-commerce websites.
On hover of the image, I'm adding a frame that moves with the mouse on top of the image.

This is done by the below code.

```
addFrame = (x,y,el) => {
    const frameEl = document.getElementById("frame");
    frameEl.style.left = x+"px";
    frameEl.style.top = y+"px";
  }

  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    this.addFrame(e.clientX,e.clientY,e.target);
  }
```

I'm trying to get the content inside this added frame - to take it and zoom it in a different view. How can I get the content that is under the frame that I added?

Answer (score 1):

the `originaltarget` property of the hover event will tell at what the mouse is pointing, but if you're hiding you images behind a trasparent barrier this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint):

```
addFrame = (x, y, el) => {
  // ...
  const elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
  if (!elem) return

  console.log(elem.textContent) 
}
```

See an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6w30jkhd/)